# Replacing a list in a program with a tuple?

Tags: python, list, input, tuples

Currently I am working on a set of exercises from my Python 2 book and am stuck on one of the problems. Here are the problems:

*"5.1 - Write a program that reads a list of numbers from the user; the list terminates when the user enters 0. After all of the input the program should print the list."*

My answer for 5.1 is as follows:

```
def main():
    L = []
    done = False
    while not done:
        num = input( "Enter a number: " )
        if num == 0:
            for i in L:
            print i
            done = True
        else:
            L.append(num)

main()
```

The issue is with exercise 5.2 which asks:

*"5.2 - Change program ( 5.1) to use a tuple instead of a list."*

Is this even possible? I was under the impression that tuples are immutable, and so they really can't be used in place of a list here. Am I right? Am I crazy? Is my Python book crazy? Is there something about tuples I'm just completely missing here? Help...

Comment: May be the exercise only wants to show that equivalent usage of tuple, and how the code differs in both the cases. Although you cannot mutate a tuple, you can create a new tuple everytime you want to append.

Comment: Hint: numbers are immutable too, still `i = i + 5` works...

Comment: Certainly a given tuple is immutable, but you can perform operations on it nonetheless. The difference is that for a mutable structure, like a list, the operation would change the list, whereas for an immutable structure like a tuple, the operation would return a new tuple. (Some operations on mutable data structures still return new data structures, though.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't modify a tuple, but you can create a new tuple by merging two tuples:

```
>>> tup = ()
>>> tup += (1,)
>>> tup
(1,)
>>> tup += (2,)
>>> tup
(1, 2)
```

Comment: Awesome, for whatever reason my book does not mention that tuples can be combined in this way.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that the exercise thinks you aught not to be building the tuple by appending elements one at a time,  In fact, you can do it all with a bit of implicit looping:

```
def get_some_input():
    return input("Enter a number: ")

def main():
    T = tuple(iter(get_some_input, 0))

    for i in T:
        print i
```

Notice we didn't write

```
T = tuple(iter(get_some_input(), 0))
#                            ^^
```

We want to pass the `get_some_input` function to `iter`, not the result of calling it.  `iter` will call the function for us repeatedly until it gets a `0`.

We also could have written:

```
def main():
    T = iter(get_some_input, 0)

    for i in T:
        print i
```

without the `tuple()`.  The difference is that we don't consume all of `iter(...)` before starting the for loop.

Comment: I learnt something new today from this. I still want my answer to win though :P Thanks Dan.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `+` operator for tuples.

```
>>> t = ()
>>> t += (9,)
>>> t
(9,)
>>> t += (3,)
>>> t
(9, 3)
```

You can initialize a tuple in different ways:

```
a = () # 0-tuple (empty tuple)
b = (item,) # 1-tuple (note the trailing comma)
c = item, # 1-tuple (note the trailing comma)
```

This is how I would write your function:

```
def main():
    l = ()
    num = None
    while num != 0:
        num = input("Enter a number: ")
        if num == 0:
            for i in l:
                print i
        else:
            l += (num,)

main()
```